# Unable to Import es6 modules from supported browser

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, momentjs

Trying to import moment.js as an es6 module. Latest Chrome version is being used.
Based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2608), I tried the src path (es6)

```
import * as moment from './node_modules/moment/src/moment'
```

While skipping the .js seem to work fine for everyone on that thread, I can't get it to work. But this works

```
import * as moment from './node_modules/moment/src/moment.js'
```

Yet the request ultimately fails with all the moment import trying to load its dependencies without the js extension

```
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8083/node_modules/moment/src/lib/utils/hooks net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) moment.js:22
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8083/node_modules/moment/src/lib/moment/moment net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) moment.js:26 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8083/node_modules/moment/src/lib/moment/calendar net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) moment.js:39 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8083/node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locale net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) moment.js:46 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8083/node_modules/moment/src/lib/duration/duration net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) moment.js:48 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8083/node_modules/moment/src/lib/units/units net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) moment.js:50 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8083/node_modules/moment/src/lib/utils/is-date net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

All I have as code is a blank index.html with this script tag

```
<script type="module" src='./main.js'></script>
```

and a main.js file with this

```
import * as _ from './node_modules/underscore/underscore.js';
import * as moment from './node_modules/moment/src/moment.js';
```

Underscore.js imports and works fine. Issue is only with moment.
What am I doing wrong? Also why is it that I can't get either of these to load without specifying the .js extension while clearly those on the ithub thread have been able to do this

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue when begin with ES6. You can try this way to import moment

```
import moment from "moment";
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "moment". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Yes, it work. But you need to make sure moment installed before. I think you run again command `npm install moment --save` to make sure lib installed

Comment: That is done. That is why moment is in my node_modules folder and my package.json is updated.

Comment: could you post version of moment.js you're using also ?

Comment: Remember - I'm not using any bundlers or module loaders. All I am doing is import directly from my script and relying the es6 capable browser to handle the import.

Comment: The latest version. 
I mean this is my code literally

Create a blank folder
1. Do npm init  

2. npm install moment  

3 create a blank html and include   

<script type="module" src='./main.js'></script>  

4. Create a main.js with this line  

import * as moment from './node_modules/moment/src/moment.js'

Load the html in chrome. Observe developer console